# Django apps: installing system-wide vs project-wide

Tags: django

What are pros/cons (regarding maintainability) of installing django apps system-wide vs installing them project-wide? Is there a recommended aproach?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'django extensions', django apps? and also what is (project-wide), virtualenv or you mean copying the app inside your project?

Comment: I am sorry for confusion. I meant django community apps like filebrowser etc. By "project-wide" I meant copying the app inside project as I did not know about virtualenv possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By django extensions, do you mean [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions)?

In all honesty, I'd steer clear of system wide installations, they instantly tie you to the system's installed versions, and if incompatibilities arise system-wide, that is a bigger issue than with a project-wide approach. In addition, they add complexity when deploying to remote services, and don't stick to the [12 Factor App](http://www.12factor.net/) principles. Keeping everything self contained, project code and its dependencies will make life easier in the long run.

I'd recommend using [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) to install your dependencies, which keeps them isolated to the project in question, and dramatically simplifies deployment.

Comment: I meant extensions in general. Am I right that the same approach should apply to Django (the "core packages") itself? I.e. for each project separate Django installation?

Comment: Yeah, I have a separate virtualenv for every project, with its own set of dependencies. It keeps everything self-contained and avoids issues with system compatibility, and makes deployment simple.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach is not to copy any reusable app inside you project. They provide extension points and settings to customize. Also, it is recommended to use virtualenv for projects and install any project specific python modules there. This will protect you from different versions conflicts.